# JTextField set text output wrong

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jtextfield

I'm trying to build a GUI for a random name generator I built, at present I'm trying to get it to print out the names when I press a button.

However instead of a list of names all I get is "[]". I don't know much about GUI programming so I'm not sure whats going wrong here.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.*;


public class Applet1 extends javax.swing.JApplet {

public static List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

public static void init(String args[])throws IOException{

      List<String> prefix = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("prefix.txt"));
      List<String> suffix = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("suffix.txt"));
      Random randomizer = new Random();


      String prefix2 = prefix.get(randomizer.nextInt(prefix.size()));
      String suffix2 = suffix.get(randomizer.nextInt(suffix.size()));                         
      Random ran = new Random();
      int C = ran.nextInt(5);

        for(int A=0;A <= 5;A++){
            if( C == 0 )
                list.add(prefix2 + " ");                
            else if( C>0 && C<3 )
                list.add(prefix2 + suffix2+ " ");                   
            else if( C>2 && C<6 )
                list.add(prefix2 + " " + prefix2 + suffix2+ " ");}}


public void init() {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting     code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the     default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Applet1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Applet1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Applet1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Applet1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the applet */
    try {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                initComponents();
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the init() method to initialize the
 * form. WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
 * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();

    setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(498, 517));

    jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "1", "5", "10", "15" }));

    jButton1.setText("Press");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setText("Select number of names and press button to Generate");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 345, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 359, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 80, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
            .addContainerGap(121, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 32, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addComponent(jComboBox1,     javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 21,     javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 389, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(33, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    jTextField1.setText(list.toString());
}                                        


// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> jComboBox1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
// End of variables declaration



}
```

As far as I can tell either I've broken the code somewhere or TextField can't handle String Arrays.

Comment: System out println this list.toString()) first, see what happens. Then you can figure out if your GUI is an issue or your logic somewhere else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method is never called:

```
public static void init(String args[])throws IOException{
```

As a result, the `list` remains empty.

Other tips/notes/questions:

1. An applet's size is set in the HTML, so the setting of any size (minimum, size or maximum) should never be called in code.

   ```
   setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(498, 517));
   ```
2. Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).
3. See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free).
4. From the look of the GUI at the size of the text field, it seems it actually needs to be a multi-line text area (`JTextArea`).

Comment: So much wrong with the OP's code, hard to know where to begin.

Comment: 1. Whenever I start this through Eclipse the applet page is too small so I keep trying to make it bigger. Never seems to work.

Comment: Also I just looked up how to make a Java GUI and there were loads of pages saying applets was the way to go. Also if I have to convert it to a TextArea that is probably going to break my existing code. Is GUI design supposed to be this hard?

Comment: *"..there were loads of pages saying applets was the way to go."* There's lots of rubbish on the internet. Further to that, applets have become much less useful in the last year. You can either trust those pages you saw, or trust the guy who is the top rated provider of answers for [`Applet`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/topusers) & [`JApplet`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/japplet/topusers), wrote the info. pages for both, the blog article that you seem to have ignored, and is constantly advising against using them, including right now (i.e. me). Your choice, really.

Comment: *"..a TextArea that is probably going to break my existing code"* Tough biccies. It will be easier to change right now, than try to force a text field to behave like a text area. *"Is GUI design supposed to be this hard?"* GUI design is an advanced topic (contrary to what most pages on the web suggest) especially when it involves GUIs that need to work on multiple platforms.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Ok so I took on your advice and reworked it in a Jframe with an TextArea and with a bit of reordering the code it now actually works: http://imgur.com/a/lCTKG

Comment: Nice one! Congratulations on sorting the problem. :)

Comment: Oh, one final tip from looking at the screenshot. Rather than set the size for a frame, ensure all the components 'know' what size you expect of them (in the case of a `JTextArea` - that is done by setting the number of columns and rows it should display). Then when all components are added, simply `pack()` the frame to have it be the exact size needed in order to display the components.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem has nothing to do with GUI or Swing code and all to do with a faulty for loop. It never loops because your condition is backwards:

```
for(int A=0;A >= 5;A++){
```

Since the `A` variable starts out being 0, it never fulfills the for loop boolean criteria of `A >= 5`, and so the loop never "loops", and the list remains empty -- which is what you're seeing.

One solution is to change that loop so that it works, and perhaps you want:

```
for(int A = 0; A <= 5; A++) {  // this loops 6 times (not 5)
```

Please check out: [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Also your class is an applet and yet you've given it a main method -- a method that **never** runs in an applet. Shouldn't that code be in an `init()` method?

Comment: thanks for noticing that, I've changed it but it still produces just "[]" either way

Comment: @Exostrike: also your class is an applet and yet you've given it a main method -- a method that **never** runs in an applet. Shouldn't that code be in an `init()` method?